# Arcmap legend: select only part of the elements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, legend, layouts

I have to export a map. In my map, I unified several features under the same colour because because for my job they are exactly the same. My problem is that, when I create a legend, I get something like this:

[image: My image with legend]

What I would like to do is to get rid of this long list of features and have in my legend only 4 elements: one marked by a green colour, one by blue color, one by pink and the last one by brown (and then to rename them).
How can I remove the legend items I do not want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are really only four colors, then you can simply go into the layer's Symbology tab and group all of the same colors together into one symbol. That will leave you with 4 symbols. Just select all the legend entries you'd like to group together, right-click them, and select "Group Values" from the context menu:[image]

Or, if the colors vary slightly you can copy and paste the layer as a new layer. Then go into the new layer's symbology and remove all the items you don't want to show and rename the ones you do want to show. Then you can just show the new layer in the legend but keep the old layer turned on.